# what is wrong with my turtle python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I wrote this code in python to learn polymorphism. I made a file `paint2.txt` which has some turtle commands in it as follows (numbers are to show width of pen, circle radius and x,y coordinate for goto):

```
pendown
beginfill 
black
circle
20 
3 
black 
endfill
goto
120 
0 
1 
red
beginfill
green
circle
20
3
yellow
endfill
penup
```

and this code reads those commands from the file and tries to parse and run them:

```
import turtle
class GoToCommand:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width=1, color='balck'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self,turtle1):
        turtle1.width(self.width)
        turtle1.pencolor(self.color)
        turtle1.goto(self.x,self.y)

class CircleCommand:
    def __init__(self, radius, width=1, color='black'):
        self.radius = radius
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle1):
        turtle1.pencolor = self.color
        turtle1.width = self.width
        turtle1.circle(self.radius)

class BeginFillCommand:

    def __init__(self,color='black'):
        self.color = color
    def draw(self,turtle1):
        turtle1.fillcolor = self.color
        turtle1.begin_fill()

class EndFillCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def draw(self,turtle1):
        turtle1.end_fill()

class PenUpCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def draw(self,turtle1):
        turtle1.penup()

class PenDownCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def draw(self,turtle1):
        turtle1.pendown()


class PyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=[]
    def append(self,item):
        self.items = self.items + [item]
    def __iter__(self):
        for c in self.items:
            yield c
def main():

    t = turtle.Turtle()
    screen = t.getscreen()

    GraphicsCommands = PyList()

    # paint2.txt is my made up file with turtle commands 
    file = open ('paint2.txt','r')
    line = file.readline()

    while line != '':
        line = line.strip()

        if line == 'goto':
            x = int(file.readline().strip())
            y = int(file.readline().strip())
            width = int(file.readline().strip())
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = GoToCommand(x,y,width,color)

        elif line == 'beginfill':
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = BeginFillCommand(color)
        elif line == 'pendown':
            cmd = PenDownCommand()

        elif line == 'penup':
            cmd = PenUpCommand()

        elif line == 'circle':
            radius = int(file.readline().strip())
            width = int(file.readline().strip())
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = CircleCommand(radius,width,color)

        elif line == 'endfill':
            cmd = EndFillCommand()

        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Unkonwn command :", line)
        GraphicsCommands.append(cmd)
        line = file.readline()

    file.close()
    for cmd in GraphicsCommands:
        cmd.draw(t)
    t.ht()
    turtle.done()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/amin/PycharmProjects/comeon/com.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()

  File "/Users/amin/PycharmProjects/comeon/com.py", line 104, in main
    cmd.draw(t)

  File "/Users/amin/PycharmProjects/comeon/com.py", line 10, in draw
    turtle1.width(self.width)

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: The error message suggests that `turtle1.width` is an integer, therefore cannot be called. Please cut the code down to a [mcve] (see e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for guidance).

Answer (score 0):

These lines are a problem:

```
turtle1.pencolor = self.color
turtle1.width = self.width
turtle1.fillcolor = self.color
```

Since `turtle1` is a turtle instance, these assignments should have been function calls:

```
turtle1.pencolor(self.color)
turtle1.width(self.width)
turtle1.fillcolor(self.color)
```

Below's a rework of your code that fixes the above and makes some other style and logic changes:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class GoToCommand:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width=1, color='black'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.width(self.width)
        turtle.pencolor(self.color)
        turtle.goto(self.x, self.y)

class CircleCommand:
    def __init__(self, radius, width=1, color='black'):
        self.radius = radius
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.pencolor(self.color)
        turtle.width(self.width)
        turtle.circle(self.radius)

class BeginFillCommand:
    def __init__(self, color='black'):
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.fillcolor(self.color)
        turtle.begin_fill()

class EndFillCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.end_fill()

class PenUpCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.penup()

class PenDownCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.pendown()

class PyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def append(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def __iter__(self):
        for c in self.items:
            yield c

def main():

    GraphicsCommands = PyList()

    # paint2.txt is my made up file with turtle commands
    file = open('paint2.txt')
    line = file.readline()

    while line != '':
        line = line.strip()

        if line == 'goto':
            x = int(file.readline().strip())
            y = int(file.readline().strip())
            width = int(file.readline().strip())
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = GoToCommand(x, y, width, color)

        elif line == 'beginfill':
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = BeginFillCommand(color)
        elif line == 'endfill':
            cmd = EndFillCommand()

        elif line == 'penup':
            cmd = PenUpCommand()
        elif line == 'pendown':
            cmd = PenDownCommand()

        elif line == 'circle':
            radius = int(file.readline().strip())
            width = int(file.readline().strip())
            color = file.readline().strip()
            cmd = CircleCommand(radius, width, color)

        else:
            raise RuntimeError("Unknown command:", line)

        GraphicsCommands.append(cmd)
        line = file.readline()

    file.close()

    tortoise = Turtle()
    screen = Screen()

    for cmd in GraphicsCommands:
        cmd.draw(tortoise)

    tortoise.hideturtle()
    screen.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```